# Jenkins powershell block does not wait until it is finished

Tags: matlab, powershell, jenkins, command-line, command-prompt

Jenkins powershell block does not wait until it is finishes it seems to go unto the next block which is a Windows Batch Command. All variables have been tested to work by doing echo on them and console output shows their correct values.

Windows Powershell block

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\bin\matlab.exe" -ArgumentList "-automation -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -r `"echo ; cd $DOMAIN\Framework\Integration; setDOMAINPath $DOMAIN; disp(iAnalytics.domain.getSingleton.getRevision); createExecutable; exit`" -logfile $logfile" -Credential $credential -wait
```

Then it goes into this right away, the executable is created by Matlab so it doesn't find it and fails job.

Windows Batch Command

```
cd %Domain%\ModuleTest
DomainTestConsistency.exe
```

So is there a way to tell Jenkins to wait for the powershell process to end and only then however long it takes to go and execute the next block? I tried adding -wait and piping | out-null but nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the $? automatic variable. (https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html) It returns as TRUE if the last operation was successful and FALSE if it failed.

```
#run first command 

if($? = "true")
{
    #run second command
}
else
{
Write-Host "first command has failed"
}
```

Comment: gives me this error:
Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo" value of type 
"System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSBoundParametersDictionary".

Comment: @JCLopez try testing the $? variable with a simple statement that you know to run successfully.